# How to retrieve the local TIMESTAMP from a Firebase database when initially was set using ServerValue.TIMESTAMP with Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I use `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to set the data and time of an item that was added to a list in a Firebase database with Android. I know that is initially set as a `Map` and when we retrieve it, we retrieve it  as a `Long` and in order to display the date and time, i use a method that looks like this:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return "date";
    }
}
```

Because i am located away from the server by 7 hours, when is display the date and time, is with 7 hours earlier. How can i display the correct date and time when using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`. Is there any possibility to this?

This how i display the time and date:

```
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    Long timeStampLong = (Long) map.get("timeStamp");
    String timeStamp = getTimeDate(timeStampLong);
    arrayList.add(timeStamp);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet formats the time in the local time zone.  You could try using this as a basis for what you need.  I'm not sure why your code doesn't work.  Can you post the `DateFormat`you are using?

```
    DatabaseReference timeRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("time-test");

    timeRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                long time = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
                String s = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date(time));
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + s);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: No data");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });

    timeRef.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: I have just edited my post to see how i display the date and time. I don't want to have `Locale.US`, as it is now. I want to display the correct time and date for each user, no matter in which location is.

Comment: Please post the string you use for `DataFormat`

Comment: It's a `Long` that looks like this: `1490898551037`. I use the default format.

Comment: I mean the string you use to create the `DateFormat` returned by `getDateTimeInstance()`. Are you just using `getDateFormat()`?

Comment: There is no format. I use the default one, which looks like this: `Mar 31, 2017, 11:20:20 AM`. But in my location is `Mar 31, 2017, 6:20:20 PM'. I want to be displayed the correct one, the last one.

Comment: I updated my answer. I get local time in output, not UTC.  Check that the device you are testing on has the correct time zone set: _Settings > Date and time_

Comment: @BobSnyder any idea about this one? thought it was simple, but seems like no one has a clue how to solve this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159855/how-do-i-make-my-button-which-is-fixed-at-the-bottom-of-a-layout-scroll-once-th?noredirect=1#com