# How do I make my button which is fixed at the bottom of a layout scroll, once the recyclerview on top grows in size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-appcompat, android-button

I have a very basic yet difficult issue where I have a button fixed at the bottom of the view,  but below recyclerview container. Once the container size grows, I want the button to go below the recyclerview (scrollable) instead of being fixed at the bottom of the view.Is there a way to achieve this?

I have looked online for a couple of ideas but didn't find anything quite like it yet.

i am basically using

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="false">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_root_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_g"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="0dp">


                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    app:subtitleTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
                    app:titleTextColor="@color/white">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nav_back_btn"
                        style="@style/Body1RegLeftBlack"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_backarrow" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/g_main_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/g"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Medium"
                        android:textColor="#de000000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal"

                        />

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/info_scrollview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/infoContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/info_location"
                            style="@style/Headline2LeftBlack"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Chronicle"
                            android:textSize="28sp"
                            tools:text="@string/five_thirty_fifth_ave" />

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/Body1RegRightRed"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/info_location"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/info_location"
                            android:text="@string/location_change"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:weightSum="2">

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/Body1RegLeftBlack"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:id="@+id/g_start_date"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular"
                            android:text="@string/g_start_date" />

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/Body1RegRightBlack"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:id="@+id/g_start_time"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular"
                            android:text="@string/g_start_time" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/registerUserSeparatorColor" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:weightSum="2">

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/Body1RegLeftBlack"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:id="@+id/g_end_date"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular"
                            android:visibility="invisible"
                            android:text="@string/g_end_date" />

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/Body1RegRightBlack"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:id="@+id/g_end_time"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular"
                            android:text="@string/g_end_time" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/registerUserSeparatorColor" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                        android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
                        android:paddingTop="30dp"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Medium"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:text="@string/g" />


                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/g_item_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:overScrollMode="never"
                        android:divider="@null"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/item_g"/>

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/Body1RegLeftRed"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:id="@+id/add_g"
                        android:lineHeight="22sp"
                        android:text="@string/add_g"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
                        android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Medium"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal"
                        android:text="@string/arrival_notifications" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:id="@+id/text_message_container"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_message"
                            style="@style/Body1RegLeftBlack"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular"
                            android:text="@string/text_message" />

                        <TextView
                            style="@style/Body2RegLeftGrey"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/text_message"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:id="@+id/tap_phone_number_text"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular"
                            android:text="@string/tap_to_add_a_phone_number" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                            android:id="@+id/text_message_switch"
                            style="@style/Color1SwitchStyle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                        android:background="@color/settingsSeparatorLineColor" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Medium"
                        android:textStyle="normal"

                        android:letterSpacing="0.07"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                        android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
                        android:text="@string/submit_list"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem above is, the submit_list btn doesnt stay fixed, if the recyclerview grows but theres still enough space to spare in the view.

I want to make it such that the button stays fixed and doesnt scroll UNTIL the size of the recyclerview goes beyond a certain limit from the bottom(not visible on the screen anymore), after which the button scrolls relative to the last item of the recyclerview and not aligned to the bottom anymore. any ideas how to go about it?

To give visual examples:
[image]

As you can see, initial screen has submit button aligned to the bottom and the rest of the content in place. As I add more users:
[image]

It still stays at the bottom since the recyclerview items are still within screen 
 now, aqs soon as i add one more item, causing the list to scroll up :
[image]

As seen I want it to go below the recyclerview instead of stay fixed at bottom of the screen (the above screenshots are from ios where it works), was wondering if we can do the same for android?

Comment: Sounds like you need something like a sticky header where header sticks at the bottom instead of at the top. Perhaps this [Sticky Header for RecyclerView](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview)? I haven't used this lib but you could modify it if needed.

Comment: @Abbas that won't work for me. Any other libs I could try? If you can explain with respect to my code that'll be helpful!  thanks

Comment: @SUPERCILEX any idea about this?

Comment: Have you tried setting property `.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` for `RecyclerView` programmatically?

Comment: @JeelVankhede that doesn't do anything for my case. Can you explain with respect to my code

Comment: When you want your `RecyclerView` grow in size whatever it wants that's the property but then you'll have to align your button below `RecyclerView` instead of bottom of the view. Also make your `NestedScrollView` to fill thew viewport using `android:fillViewPort="true"`.

Comment: @AngelaHeely So now your button is fixed and you want to stay below the RecyclerView once it has more elements, right? So you want the button the be every time under the last element. Why not to insert the button in the RecyclerView?

Comment: @AlexMamo I can't insert it in recyclerview as I am planning to insert more elements after recyclerview soon , which will stay between recyclerview and this submit button , some ui elements like textview etc  and some other buttons etc. so it might not be feasible to insert it in recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [demo link](https://github.com/MARGI3/CoordinateLayoutScroll)

And a [Gif link](https://gfycat.com/AncientBlackandwhiteAnteater)

```
public class WeirdStickyBottomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private TextView mStickyView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weird_sticky_bottom);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mStickyView = findViewById(R.id.sticky);
        Button mAddButton = findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        Button mDeleteButton = findViewById(R.id.button_delete);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        hideStickyLayoutIfNeed();

        mAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAdapter.addItems();
                hideStickyLayoutIfNeed();
            }
        });

        mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAdapter.deleteItems();
                hideStickyLayoutIfNeed();
            }
        });

        mStickyView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(WeirdStickyBottomActivity.this, "Sticky Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void hideStickyLayoutIfNeed() {
        mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                int firstVisible = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                int lastCompletelyVisible = mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                //adapter list size display beyond the screen
                if (firstVisible > 0 || lastCompletelyVisible < mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1) {
                    mAdapter.addStickyItem(true);
                    if (mStickyView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        mStickyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                } else if (firstVisible == 0 && lastCompletelyVisible == mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1) {
                    if (mStickyView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                        mStickyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private static class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemHolder> {

        private int mStickyIndex = -1;

        static final int HOLDER_TYPE_NORMAL = 1;
        static final int HOLDER_TYPE_STICKY = 2;

        private List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        private Context mContext;

        MyAdapter(Context context) {
            this.mContext = context;
            addItems();
        }

        public void addItems() {
            boolean hasStickyItem = mStickyIndex > 0;
            if (hasStickyItem) {
                dataList.remove(mStickyIndex);
                mStickyIndex = -1;
            }
            int size = dataList.size();
            for (int i = size; i < size + 5; i++) {
                dataList.add("This is a item");
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void deleteItems() {
            int size = dataList.size();
            if (size < 6) {
                return;
            }
            boolean hasStickyItem = mStickyIndex > 0;
            if (hasStickyItem) {
                dataList.remove(mStickyIndex);
                mStickyIndex = -1;
            }
            if (size > size - 5) {
                dataList.subList(size - 5, size - 1).clear();
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void addStickyItem(boolean notify) {
            //did not add sticky item before
            if (mStickyIndex <= 0) {
                mStickyIndex = dataList.size();
                dataList.add(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.sticky_layout));
                if (notify) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return ItemHolder.create(parent, viewType == HOLDER_TYPE_STICKY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.bind(dataList.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return dataList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            if (position == mStickyIndex) {
                return HOLDER_TYPE_STICKY;
            }

            return HOLDER_TYPE_NORMAL;
        }
    }

    private static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView textView;
        private boolean isSticky;

        private ItemHolder(@NonNull View itemView, boolean isSticky) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            this.isSticky = isSticky;
        }

        void bind(String text) {
           textView.setText(text);
            if (isSticky) {
                textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Sticky Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                textView.setBackgroundColor(textView.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            } else {
                textView.setOnClickListener(null);
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }

        static ItemHolder create(ViewGroup parent, boolean isSticky) {
            return new ItemHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false), isSticky);
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$Behavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="Collapse">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tb_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:title="@string/app_name">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_add"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/button_add" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_delete"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/button_delete" />


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sticky_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sticky"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/sticky_layout" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! is there any easier way to do this without adding "StickyBottomScrollingBehavior" ?

Comment: If your AppBarLayout is not complex just a Toolbar inside, you can got this effect without  `StickyBottomScrollingBehavior `, This behavior is to help you handle with Complex AppBarLayout scroll range. But you still need to change your layout from a nested `recyclerview` in `nesctedscrollview` to a `recyclerview` with multiple type. And just detect the `onScrolled` to do the sticky effect and the code would be very simple.

Comment: just checked the demo. The effect I am looking for is a little different than a sticky layout. So basically, I have my dynamic recyclerview. below it is a submit button (which is all the way to the bottom of the parent layout) , as i add one item to the recyclerview, as long as its still within the view of the screen and theres enough space between the submit button and recyclerview, submit button stays at the parent bottom, but as soon as recyclerview grows submit button goes below the recyclerview and say if you have say 20 items , submit button wont even be visible on the screen

Comment: cont... it will be below the recyclerview and not visible on the screen until you scroll all the way to the bottom of the recyclerview

Comment: @AngelaHeely I have update my answer, take a look. Maybe this is what you want.

Comment: Jeffery Ma any idea about this one ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598276/how-do-i-pass-a-multi-part-body-parameter-for-rxjava2-androidnetworking-post-req

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using **`ConstraintLayout`**

**SAMPLE CODE**

> layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnBottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    DataAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        addDataToList();

        adapter = new DataAdapter(this, arrayList);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void addDataToList() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            arrayList.add("NILU_PILU :-> " + i);
        }
    }

}
```

> DataAdapter class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public DataAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.aaa, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvText.setText(arrayList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvText;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
        }
    }
}
```

> **OUTPUTS**

[image: Output when list has few items]

[image: Output when list has more items]

Comment: thanks so much! I am currently using coordinator layout, should i convert it to parent layout or add constraintlayout as a sub layer?

Comment: Also from the screenshots seems like continue button is not at the bottom of the parent layout in the first screen,rather at the bottom of recycler view

Comment: any idea about this one ?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598276/how-do-i-pass-a-multi-part-body-parameter-for-rxjava2-androidnetworking-post-req

Answer (score 1):

Create `button.xml` inside your layout folder and obviously create a button inside it.

Add some things to your adapter:

```
//This will check if the current position is past the last item in your list, 
//if it is then it will return the button layout value to this method

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int pos) {
return (pos == mItems.size()) ? R.layout.button : R.layout.mItem;
}
```

And do something like this in your onCreateViewHolder

```
@Override
public mViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

View itemView;

if(viewType == R.layout.item){
    itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, 
parent, false);
}

else {
    itemView = 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.button, parent, 
false);
}

return new mViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

And in your OnBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(mViewHolder mHolder, int pos) {
if(pos == mItems.size()) {
    mHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Do something....
        }
    });
}
else {
    String members = mItems.get(pos);
    mHolder.title.setText(members);
}
}
```

Also do change your, getItemCount, to get that extra item (in your case, the button)

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return mItems.size() + 1;
}
```

Also don't forget to find your button in mViewHolder (you already know that i guess) `mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);`

This will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
See if this works  

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work. i will update the question, with my actual layout, hope that helps

Comment: updated my code with the actual layout. i m open to any suggestions from switching it to constraint layout or anything ,so that the submit button stays relative to the recyclerview after scrolling

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do pagination then you can try below layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        tools:itemCount="5"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_recycler_tasker_home" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rvItem"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="MyButton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

By doing this all the recyclerview's items gets loaded at one go as recyclerView's height is wrap_content it will acquire only height that is required for all items, and then after recyclerview you can see your button

Comment: I wanted to align my button to parents bottom. and then once the recyclerview grows in size i expect it to push it down (so its below the last item in the recycler view but no more at the parents bottom) . any idea how to achieve that? the above code doesnt achieve that